# Ramen eating etiquette

Tags: japan, food-and-drink, etiquette

In Western and westernized media, characters are shown sucking up ramen noodles bowls then drinking the soup from the bowl at street side shops.

What is actually appropriate when eating at a traditional ramen shop?

Comment: https://youtu.be/jn9DQ6Awcxo?t=1m30s

Comment: @oleksandr a better thing to do for Stack Exchange would be to cite the video in an answer that summarizes what is said in it.

Comment: Ramen eating "etiquette", best joke ever.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's still the appropriate word lol

Comment: @Ifusaso it took me 4 sec to google the answer; it would make me feel like I'm hunting a mythical reputation point if I posted it as an answer and expected it to be marked as such. It's a shame you are so lazy you made se users to make research for you.

Comment: Or, maybe, I don't have context to know which of the *dozens* of YouTube videos are reputable sources. Maybe I was hoping for someone with anecdotal evidence or someone actually familiar with the culture in Travel SE.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know, the comic masterpiece *Tampopo* is maybe the most famous Japanese film of all time.  (It's the cultural equivalent of say *Ferris Bueller*, *Home Alone*, *The Jerk*.) It deals with noodle slurping and other aspects of food culture.  The noodle-slurping scenes are iconic and all other noodle-slupring vide,s comedy etc is just based on it.  JPatokal has explained all this in the excellent answr!

Comment: Ramen Master:
https://youtu.be/6WrkdTrrwew

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Slurping noodles is fine.** The theory is that sucking in air reduces the odds of getting burned and/or shows appreciation to the chef.

**Drinking from the bowl**, however, is a mild *faux pas*.  While this is expected for Japanese soups like miso, which are served from small bowls without a spoon, ramen is considered a Chinese dish and it's served in large bowls that are awkward to drink from, so there's always a spoon on the side.  The broth is usually also very salty and fatty, so most people don't eat all of it.  All that said, ramen is casual fast food and it's common to see people drink it up directly.

Last but not least, some advice from the Ramen Master in cult classic [タンポポ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampopo), who drinks his soup straight from the bowl: https://youtu.be/C1sbnXcVeBE

Disclaimer: the movie is a comedy and the scene is tongue in cheek... but it's funny precisely because some Japanese do take their ramen *very* seriously!

Comment: "ramen is considered a Chinese dish and it's served in large bowls that are awkward to drink from, so there's always a spoon on the side" - which, as far as I can extrapolate, might not stop any *Chinese* person from drinking directly from the bowl nonetheless. Of course, the Japanese assumption of how to deal with Chinese dishes may differ.

Comment: The practical difference in Japan is that Chinese soups are served with spoons, so you can choose to drink or use the spoon, while Japanese ones are not, so drinking is the only option.  What Chinese people do in China is another question.

Comment: The answer is so good I cannot stand a single imperfection in it: it is Ta*m*popo, not Ta*n*popo (sorry, not enough reputation to silently correct it)

Comment: It is "Tanpopo" using Modified Hepburn Romanisation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Syllabic_n

Comment: @thenickdude: The "official?" English name (on http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092048/ anyway) is Tampopo, so that's probably the more useful name to use in the answer, regardless of Tanpopo also being a valid spelling for the Japanese word.

Comment: Worth adding a note about what to do with chopsticks for the next user who searches for "ramen eating etiquette"? Before going to Japan I read that it was very bad etiquette to leave chopsticks stuck into the bowl, and you're meant to place them on the edge of the bowl.

Comment: As with wine and coffee, slurping should also aerate the broth and bring out more flavour

Comment: The film is simply called "Tampopo" (with an M), and it's probably the single most well-known Japanese film title in English.  There would be many ways to "translate", "phonetically spell," etc. the original Japanese title into English. (Such as "dandelion", "my sidekick," etc.)  All of which have no connection to anything.  It is never, ever, spelled any other way.  You might as well offer one of the many alternate phonetic spellings of Pokemon, Totoro, Toyota, Samurai, Sushi, etc. Note that **in the film** when you see it written in English, it is of course "Tampopo".

Comment: I've corrected the movie's title to the actual one.